# How to scale multiple handles of curve simultaneously without changing their anchor positions? ie. To sharpen corners of a "mouth"?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I am making a simple cartoon mouth with a curve which I will then solidify, convert to mesh, and use to cut out of a head with a bool.

I am trying to "sharpen" the two corners of the mouth by scaling the handles towards their anchor points:

[image]

For example, manually roughly if I scale them both down to look approximately symmetric I might get:

[image]

I saw a video of someone do something similar on Youtube but while adjusting them both at the same time so I know it's possible However, I cannot figure out how to do it.

If I select the 4 handles and scale it warps everything bizarrely. If I select the two anchor points then scale, it must use either one handle or the other as an pivot point and brings them closer together.

I can obviously eyeball it and scale them each one at a time as shown above. But I am wondering what the correct way is I saw on Youtube to scale them simultaneously/symmetrically to just sharpen the corners without changing any positions of points.

Also, I understand there is no way to use a curve as a bool, which is why I will convert to mesh after. Is there any other good way of accomplishing this? ie. using curves to make a cartoon mouth then cutting it out of the head? Ideally I wish I didn't have to convert to mesh. A curve mouth is easier to manipulate.

Thanks.

Comment: Set "pivot point" (at top or bottom of 3D view) to "individual origins", select all handles you want to affect, then scale. You could do it non-destructively (what you're after with not having to convert to mesh) by creating a mesh object and using geometry nodes, referencing your curve object, to create a mesh object that you could use as a cutter for a live boolean modifier.

Comment: Little hard to get an efficient workflow, but you can select all the points and then use box select to deselect the origin. That way you can use scale to also symetrically move handles towards each other.

Answer (score 3):

As Nathan commented, first set "individual origins", then select all handles you want and then press "S" and they will all be scaled. Here a small video tutorial: (which i think is always easier to follow than reading text - just my opinion)

[image]